# Search For a code in Excel File without Excel Installed

Tags: c#, excel

I made an application C# that searches for a code entered by the user in an excel file and then it displays some description corresponding to the code.

The excel have file have 2 Columns. One is code one is description. e.g

```
code  description
1     hello
2     this is
3     a test
```

So if User enters 3. It will return with "a test"

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

However, it came to my attention that this will only work if you have Excel Installed on your computer. I need something that doesn't require you to have excel installed on your computer.

The code I have for my current program.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Excel_Finder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label3.Text = "Searching For Code!";
            label3.Visible = true;
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            string path = textBox3.Text;
            Excel.Workbook workBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
            Excel.Worksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
            Excel.Range range = workSheet.Columns[1];//Range of Column A
            Excel.Range findRange;
            string strToFind = textBox1.Text;
            string description;
            findRange = range.Find(strToFind);
            if (findRange is null)
            {
                label3.Text = "Code " + textBox1.Text + " Does not Exist!";               
            }
            else
            {
                description = workSheet.Cells[findRange.Row, 2].VALUE;
                textBox2.Text = description;                             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works as expected but as I said this does not work if I don't have excel installed. I found some other libraries that does not require excel to be installed but I am not sure how to use them to do this same thing. If someone can provide an example that would be great with any library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did come across this library earlier on, but again I am not sure how to use that library for my needs. I am relatively new to C#. If you have an example for it or something similar, that would be great.

Comment: You can read Excel files without Office for example with **OleDbConnection** (Jet.OLEDB or ACE.OLEDB for the connection string)

Comment: ya but would you have an example of that for what I need it for by any chance.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to use that library, how did you write the code in the question? That code is way more complex than what you need to do with EPPlus.

Comment: Obviously by looking for examples of something similar on google which I was able to find and then customizing to my needs. Not able to find anything similar for EPPlus for all the time I spent looking for it at least.

Comment: There you go: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/tree/master/SampleApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many excel libraries in C#, most used, fast and easy one is EPPLUS.

Here is sample of reading a file (source: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started)

```
//Open the workbook (or create it if it doesn't exist)
    var fi=new FileInfo(@"c:\workbooks\myworkbook.xlsx")
    using (var p = new ExcelPackage(fi))
        {
           //Get the Worksheet created in the previous codesample. 
           var ws=p.Workbook.Worksheets["MySheet"];
           Set the cell value using row and column.
           ws.Cells[2, 1].Value = "This is cell A2. It is set to bolds";
           //The style object is used to access most cells formatting and styles.
           ws.Cells[2, 1].Style.Font.Bold=true;
           //Save and close the package.
           p.Save();
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. using something similar to that, I got it to work the way I wanted it to. Thanks.

Comment: If you solved your question by this answer, please upvote